# OpenSSL compression on iOS Device

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, static-libraries, zlib

I use openssl in my ios project and so I build a static library with the build script from github: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone . I included the libcrypto.a and libssl.a in my xcode project and can succesfully use all openssl functions. 
Now I want to support compression with openssl. The problem: the created library not seem to support any compression method (SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods() is empty).

So I add zlib-dynamic property:

```
./Configure iphoneos-cross --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk" zlib-dynamic
```

I added libz.dylib to the link with section:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ljlqmb.jpg

Now the compression works in simulator but not on the device. As far as I know dynamic librarys are not allowed on iOS. However libz.dylib is a system library. Can openssl use the integrated zlib on a device or not? If not, is it possible to use openssl with compression on a iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, iOS already contains `libz.dylib`. As such, you should be able to link to it:

- In "Build Phases" remove `libz.dylib` you've added;
- In "Build Settings" locate setting named "Other Linker Flags" and add `-lz` to it;
- Note that `zlib.h` is also available as part of iOS SDK, so no need to have another one.

This should allow your app to be built for both Simulator and the device.

**EDIT**

The above doesn't resolve the issue. The actual problem is caused by `zlib-dynamic` OpenSSL Configure. With this option, OpenSSL tries to load `libz.so` at runtime (and fails to do so because it is named `libz.dylib` on iOS). This is easy to fix by replacing `zlib-dynamic` with `zlib` and re-building OpenSSL. If using newly built library results in linker errors please check the first part of the answer.

Comment: Your solution comes to the same result: I can compile the app and it works in the simulator and on a device but the compression works only in simulator. Are there any other solutions to get compression to work? Maybe build openssl with included zlib?

Comment: Sorry, I must've misread/misunderstood the question: I was under impression you're getting *build* errors for a device. If you're seeing no build/link errors but different runtime behaviour then I think it's worth looking at the OpenSSL `Configure`/`make` logs. Perhaps `Configure` is not finding something it needs to enable `libz` for device builds.

Comment: OK, I've spent some time investigating, and it looks like the root of the problem is the `zlib-dynamic` option. Replace it with `zlib` and you're good. Don't forget to link to `libz`! I have verified by building OpenSSL via the script you link to. `zlib-dynamic` causes an error because OpenSSL cannot open `libz.so` at runtime – it is called `libz.dylib` on iOS; `zlib` will try to resolve symbols at link time (and cause linking errors if you don't pass `-lz`). Additionally, if you're only modifying 'iphone-cross' target then 64-bit simulator won't have zlib support.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I used zlib no-shared no-zlib-dynamic options. Compression works now on Simulator and device.